# MySQL query to extract first word from a field

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I would like to run a query that returns the first word only from a particular field, this field has multiple words separated by spaces, I assume I may need to carry out some regex work to accomplish this? I know how to do this using a few ways in PHP but this would best be carried out on the database side. Any ideas much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

`SUBSTRING_INDEX`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(`name`, ' ', 1);
```

Comment: Use `SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(`name`, ' ', -1);` to select the last word.

Comment: What about those records with only one word and no space?

Comment: is there any way we can get the first word regardless?

Comment: Well, you said the record has only one word and no space, so the "full value" means that word, in that case. Not sure what's unclear, just go ahead and try it out.

Answer (score 23):

Here you go :)

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX( `field` , ' ', 1 ) AS `field_first_word`
FROM `your_table`
```

Answer (score 5):

```
select 
    substring(test_field, 1, instr(test_field, ' ')) 
from 
    test_table
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
  SUBSTR(field_name, 1, LOCATE(' ', field_name)) AS first_word
FROM
  table
```

Comment: Need to add a -1 or you get an extra space.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code may do the trick

```
select regexp_substr("Héctor-99 Eduvijes Uribe Curiel", '[[:graph:]]*')`
```

Output: Héctor-99

This is pretty similar from the others answers, but works in a different way, here you can find out more about it! https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html

Another optional could be:

```
select regexp_substr("Some name", '[a-z]+')
```

Ouput: Some

Inside the brackets you can put anything you want, learn some Regex you'll be able to do great things.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.