# How do I group by first name in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where there is a full name column. I want to get either the unique given name or given names sorted by how many times they occur.

```
fullname
-----------
Barack Hussein Obama
Michael Jackson
William Jefferson Blythe
Michael Bloomberg
```

so the output will be either

```
Barack Hussein Obama
William Jefferson Blythe
```

Or

```
Barack Hussein Obama
William Jefferson Blythe
Michael Jackson
Michael Bloomberg
```

Or

```
1|Barack
1|William
2|Michael
```

Something like that. My aim is to see the foreign students in my database. I only have their full name to make a guess.

Comment: Split the column into three.

Comment: @Vesper, there are full names with 2,3,4,5 "names". Like "raja muhammad omer faiz" or "muhammad salihudden bn mohamed bas" or "lucie helene marie sourice".

Comment: @ilhan Can you say which part is the "given name", then? Is it just the first name? Everything except the last name?

Comment: @Carsten, the first part is the given name.

Comment: You can extract the first word, if you're sure that's the name you want, with a method like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689858/mysql-query-to-extract-first-word-from-a-field and then handle the GROUP_BY separately.

Comment: Yeah, if you need the given name separately store it separately, it should be easy to do in whatever language is connecting to the db, but a pain if you are relying on MySQL for string functions...

Comment: Take look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x  Perhaps this can help you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullname,' ',1)` to extract the "given name" as per your definition.

You can then use this for grouping or sorting as you seem fit, e.g.

```
SELECT COUNT(*),SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullname,' ',1) AS givenname 
 FROM yourtable 
 GROUP BY givenname;
```